# Comparing the NSLayoutAttribute in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

Following code was working well with swift 2 but it is not working with swift 3.

```
    let constraints: NSArray = contentView.constraints as NSArray
    let indexOfConstraint = constraints.indexOfObject (passingTest: { (constraint, idx, stop) in
        return (constraint.firstItem ).tag == bubbleTag && (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.left || constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.right)
    })
```

I am getting following error:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and
>   'NSLayoutAttribute'

I am getting this error for following line:

```
constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.left
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That error message is showing only the first error that your code may cause, and you may need some more fixes to work on it.

Assuming you are using `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`) for `constraints`, why don't you declare `constraints` as `[NSLayoutAttribute]`?

With that change, you may need to fix some other parts, but the code getting the index can be written like this:

```
let indexOfConstraint = constraints.index {constraint in
    return constraint.firstItem.tag == bubbleTag && (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.left || constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.right)
}
//indexOfConstraint becomes `Int?`, so you may need to use Optional binding
if let index = indexOfConstraint {
    //Do something for found case
} else {
    //Do something for not-found case
}
```

If you cannot change the type of `constraints` globally, you can put this sort of code in your local code-block just before the code above.

```
guard let constraints = constraints as? [NSLayoutConstraint] else {
    fatalError("something wrong with `constraints`")
}
```

Comment: Please check my edit. I shared my constaints line. Also I found this code on internet so I don't know the logic actually.

Comment: @TolgayToklar as a rule of thumb, you should probably try to understand the code before implementing it.......

Comment: @TolgayToklar, assuming your `contentView` is a (subtype of) `UIView`, do you know the `constraints` property's type is `[NSLayoutAttribute]` ? Why you dare cast it to `NSArray`, which I recommend you NOT to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

Please, check below updated code:

```
let constraints: NSArray = contentView.constraints as NSArray
let indexOfConstraint = constraints.indexOfObject (passingTest:){ ( constraint, idx, stop) in
     return ((constraint as AnyObject).firstItem as! UIView).tag == bubbleTag && ((constraint as AnyObject).firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.left || (constraint as AnyObject).firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.right)
}
```